# php remove extra brackets from xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to parse a huge xml of photo albums. I'm using PHP SimpleXML to parse, however it fails on some entries with errors because extra brackets may appear in some cases, see 'description' or 'CameraModel' tags.

How do I clean up xml before loading it with SimpleXML? If possible, replace extra brackets with '_' underscore.

Here is my xml:

```xml
<values>
<photos>
<photo><photoID>4521</photoID>
<name></name>
<description>Seattle<3</description>
<fileName>S5001497.jpg</fileName>
<fileSize>177513</fileSize>
<fileSizeOriginal>2359669</fileSizeOriginal>
<width>1200</width>
<height>900</height>
<exif><CameraModel><Digimax S500 / Kenox S500</CameraModel>
<CameraMake>Samsung Techwin</CameraMake>
<DateTime>2008-07-12 17:37:24</DateTime>
<Version>220</Version>
<SourceWidth>2592</SourceWidth>
<SourceHeight>1944</SourceHeight>
<Orientation>1</Orientation>
<FlashUsed>89</FlashUsed>
<FocalLength>5.8</FocalLength>
<ExposureTime>0.033333</ExposureTime>
<Brightness></Brightness>
<ApertureFNumber>2.8</ApertureFNumber>
<ISO>177</ISO>
<ExposureProgram>0</ExposureProgram>
</exif>
<type>photo</type>
<GPS></GPS>
</photo>
</photos>
</values>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the XML file? The extract brackets are not valid XML and should be entered as `&lt;`

Comment: That isn't XML as far as any parser is concerned. The problem should be fixed by using the entity reference (`&lt;`) at the source.

Comment: I have no control over XML, it is generated by a reputable website and they will not change the xml.

Comment: It's not very reputable if they are sending invalid XML.

Comment: even this site (stackoverflow.com) recognized the code correctly, i mean color coding the tags vs values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex

```
print preg_replace("/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>.*)(<)(.*<\/\\2>)/", "$1_$4", $xml);
```

Comment: @Vital why is that almost?

Comment: and the place where CameraModel is valid (has no extra brackets) it also changed it to _CameraModel

Comment: why a tag changed to _photoID & _CameraModel become problem?

Comment: i guess, i have to correct myself... between photo and photoID tags there is no space. same thing between exif and CameraModel.   (i will change the xml above.)

Comment: i have changed the xml, sorry i tried to make it more readable.

Comment: I've changed my answer